# TCP/IP how to get target computer's MAC address

Tags: networking

Does computer A need the MAC address of computer B 
in order to send a message to computer B? If so, how does A get B's  MAC address?

Answer (score 2):

If both computers are in the same LAN yes.
If they are not in the same LAN communication goes via a router or bridge. In that case A needs to know the MAC of the router (or bridge) that will forward the traffic to B.

In both cases the ARP protocol is used by A to determine the target's MAC address.
Basically (heavily simplified) this is a broadcast to ALL computers in the LAN asking the requested target to respond.
The target will respond with a "I'm here" message and A can then learn the MAC-address from that response (because the MAC of target is in that message as source-MAC address).

For full details how this works Google for ARP protocol.

Comment: Because of abmiguity in the common use of the term LAN, I'd note on @Tonny 's excellent answer that LAN, in this instance, means "local logical subnetwork(s) that Computer A is directly connected to".
    
All IP devices in the same subnet should know each other's MAC address due to ARP broadcast; and the subnetwork's gateway (router device) will know the MAC of adjacent connected gateways and subnetworks that can be used to get your communication to Computer B if it is on a different subnet.  But yes, the TCP protocol is built upon knowing the MAC address of the device you are talking to.

Comment: @Ruscal Network these days has become almost completely synonymous to TCP/IP over Ethernet. So I just didn't bother :-) For the record: I started doing networks in the early 80's. Novell (the network stack, not the OS), ArcNet, 3Com, Netbios, Banyan Vines, Decnet, Netbuei, IPX/SPX, TokenRing. I worked with all of these. These days it is a lot simpler with just ipv4 and ipv6 to worry about in most cases. Man... I'm getting old....